# zfs remove device from pool

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zfs, zfsonlinux

Before you read the title and roll your eyes, I've already read all of the various answers, posts, and articles that say you can't shrink a pool once you've made it. However, I saw [this](https://www.delphix.com/blog/delphix-engineering/openzfs-device-removal) post which claims to do exactly that (i.e. remove a device from an active pool and shrink the pool to use the remaining disks). I tried to do it on my storage host and got this:

```
root@file2:~# zpool remove datastore sdh
cannot remove sdh: only inactive hot spares, cache, top-level, or log devices can be removed
```

So, I'm guessing I'm using an older/different version of zfs. Does anyone have experience with using this functionality? Am I totally wrong and it's still impossible?

If it matters, I'm running Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Looks like this will be available in the 0.8.0 release (currently at the rc2 level, not yet production) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714527/removing-disk-from-zfs-pool-permanently for more discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device removal is available for [zfs](/questions/tagged/zfs) on [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) from [v8.0-rc1](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/releases/tag/zfs-0.8.0-rc1)  (2018-09-08):

> **New Features**
>
> - Native encryption
> - Device removal
> - ...

Also available in [solaris](/questions/tagged/solaris)  from [11.4 Beta](https://blogs.oracle.com/solaris/oracle-solaris-zfs-device-removal).

Note: As of 2019-02-17 the latest [zfsonlinux](/questions/tagged/zfsonlinux) is v8.0-rc3 and the stable v8.0 will be a future release.

Comment: Changed this to the accepted answer as it is more accurate now.

Answer (score 3):

This feature is not yet part of ZFS on Linux. There is an open feature request to implement it:

https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/3371

Answer (score 1):

> So, I'm guessing I'm using an older/different version of zfs.

Yes, you are using ZFS on Linux and the blog is about OpenZFS on Delphix. They are not the same thing.

> Am I totally wrong and it's still impossible?

You already know the answer to this question, at least in relation to the version of ZoL on Ubuntu

> > root@file2:~# zpool remove datastore sdh
> >     cannot remove sdh: only inactive hot spares, cache, top-level, or log devices can be removed

Comment: I get this complaint from zpool even when trying to remove a cache drive, removing it by its gid instead of its dev device worked (show with `#zpool status -g`), maybe I just need a healthy dose of manuals, thought I don't see in the manual anything that clarifies valid "device"-syntax